# Where is the krb5.ini file in alter Windows file gone?

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, krb5.ini

at least till Windows XP there was a krb5.ini file if you join a domain with specific settings for the Kerberos REALM. Since Vista or 7 this file is not needed anymore. I am trying to find more information about this but got stuck. Where are the settings from the krb5.ini file now? Got it removed already in Vista or just with Windows 7? 
For Java applications you can either use the "system default" or you can specify a location to the krb5.ini file. But if you use the default on these later OS's it still works but not telling where the information for KDC and so on come from.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: use -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true with a sample java program and paste the logs. They generally tell where the krb5 default location is.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Windows 10** the file can be found in:

`C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini`

In case the file does not exist, it can be manually created by the user. After changing the file, make sure you **restart the Kerberos Client** in order to load the updated configuration.